# Why might computers in wireless networks receive packet that may be part of a message for itself?

Tags: wireless

I don't quite understand why 'wireless' is a correct answer for the first box in the left column (i.e. computers in wireless networks receive packet that may be part of a message for itself). The question and answers are as below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You must think about why wireless and bus topologies are similar. They are both half-duplex technologies, and every frame sent "on the wire" is sent to every host. That means every host will hear every frame, and some of those frames must be for a listening host.

Comment: That actually makes sense. Does that mean star and mesh topologies are full-duplex?

Comment: Start and mesh topologies are probably full duplex, although they could be half duplex. The difference is that the links are point-to-point links, not shared among all the hosts (requires half duplex).